# Can Tables be Created in a Rich Text Format Field?

Tags: visualforce, richtextarea

Is it possible to create tables in a Rich Text Field?

From the image below, I could not see any icon that will create a table in the Rich Text Field.

Is this a limitation for Salesforce? Or is there really a way to add tables?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot add tables directly in Rich Text Area, however, you can copy and paste them from MS Excel, for example.

The result will be like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. May I know if this can be done only in classic? Or can we do the same thing in Lightning?

Comment: @JerardDelaVictoria Sure, same thing for Lightning.

Comment: Ok,so I copied some cells (4x4) in excel and pasted it into Salesforce. Using Mozilla Firefox lightning, all I saw where the numbers in the table but the table structure itself is not copied. When done via classic, we can add a table but no borders are visible. Also, the color formatting in the table is lost.

Comment: It seems like Excel has a problem with saving its formatting in SF, try to copy-paste the table from Google Tables.

Comment: Ok I tried it with Google Sheets and it works! Thanks for the help, this saves us a lot of investigation time!